# Is it best practice to have separate apps for different teams within an organisation?

Tags: lightning-apps, bestpractice

This is a super basic question, so apologies if this is the wrong platform. My experience is largely with platforms like Zendesk and Kayako and have done a bunch of learning through Trailhead, however there is limited information that clearly outlines what best practice is when setting up your instance. I guess there are so many way to go about it. That being said, our business model is relatively basic, so I wanted to know if it is best practice to have an app for each type of business function

For example:

1. An app for the sales team and an app for the service team
2. or would you have both teams us the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it would be considered a best practice to expose all the objects a user needs to perform a particular business function as a single app. Salesforce comes with some of these out of the box. You can use these as is, or customize them to fit your needs. For example, the Sales app includes objects useful for a typical Sales [Persona](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/ux-personas-for-salesforce/get_started_with_personas), the Marketing app for a typical Marketing Persona, and a Support app for a typical Support Persona. I'd start by playing around in each of these apps before you get serious with customization to get a feel for what each of these apps are designed for. Salesforce is a great platform, though I agree it can be overwhelming for someone just starting out. I'd also recommend that you take some other [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/) that you find interesting.